# Flutter Text widget not bounded by parent's size

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code for a Cell item in ListView:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 120.0,
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 4.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: new Image.network(
                movie.imageUrl,
                height: 120.0,
                width: 80.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(movie.title),
                  new Flexible(
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
                      child: new Text(
                          movie.about,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Which shows the following: [image]

When the movie description is bigger than the cell size, the text overflows, i want it to clip, or end in an ellipsis and cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,` to clip the text and show an elipsis:

```
child: new Text(
    'test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
```

However your next question will be about wrapping, and I can't figure that one out :(

Comment: Yep i already tried this, but then it changes to a single line with the ellipsis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try "maxLines":

```
child: Text(
    'test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ', 
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    maxLines: 5,
)
```